# Eliminating numbers from a Chinese Remainder Theorem:

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Say I have the following congruences:

n = 1 mod 2

n = 2 mod 3

n = 3 mod 4

n = 4 mod 5

n = 5 mod 6

n = 0 mod 7

I know that for n = 5 mod 6, then n = 5 mod 2 and n = 5 mod 3, or n = 1 mod 2 and n = 2 mod 3, which are already included in the original condition. I can then remove the n = 5 mod 6 congruence. Leaving me with:

n = 1 mod 2

n = 2 mod 3

n = 3 mod 4

n = 4 mod 5

n = 5 mod 6

n = 0 mod 7

However, I want to somehow get rid of either the mod 2 or mod 4 condition so I can make everything coprime and solve using CRT. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also drop the condition $n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, since $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ implies it. This leaves you with
\begin{align}
   n &\equiv 2 \pmod 3 \\
   n &\equiv 3 \pmod 4 \\
   n &\equiv 4 \pmod 5 \\
   n &\equiv 0 \pmod 7
\end{align}
and now $3,4,5,7$ are pairwise relatively prime.

In general, one way to find the right relatively prime moduli (maybe not the most economical one) is to:

1. Take all the primes dividing the current moduli: $2, 3, 5, 7$ in your case.
2. For each prime $p$, find the highest power $p^k$ it occurs with, and deduce $n \bmod p^k$ from the condition $p^k$ occurs in.
3. The collection of conditions on $n \bmod p^k$ for all the primes in the problem is equivalent to the original set of conditions.

For example, if you knew $n \bmod 24$ and $n \bmod 18$, the two primes are $2$ and $3$, and their highest powers are $8$ and $9$. You can deduce $n \bmod 8$ from $n \bmod 24$ and you can deduce $n \bmod 9$ from $n \bmod 18$.

But, of course, [lab bhattacharjee's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2538857) solves this particular problem much more quickly.

Comment: Why does n = 3 (mod 4) imply n = 1 (mod 2), is it because a number that is congruent to 3 mod 4 will be odd, and n = 1 mod 2 is basically saying the same thing?

Comment: If $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then $n = 4k+3$, so $n = 2(2k+1) + 1$, which tells us $n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$. A similar argument works whenever one modulus divides another.

Comment: Another argument: if $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then the difference $n-3$ is a multiple of $4$. This means it's a multiple of $2$, so $n \equiv 3 \pmod 2$. But that's the same as saying $n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$.

Comment: alright, so would this be more of a "look at it and reason a bit" kind of step rather than an algorithmic deal

Comment: "Algorithmicly"  $b \equiv k \mod nm\implies b \equiv k \mod n$ and $b \equiv k \mod m$.  So $n\equiv 3 \mod 4$ implies $n \equiv 3 \mod 2 \equiv 1 \mod 2$.  It's not actually a profound result.  It's the other way that more important and difficlut.  $b \equiv k \mod m$ implies $b \equiv k + mj \mod mn$.

Comment: Just looking at the b= k mod nm ⟹ b = k mod n and b=k mod m result there, I learned that as an iff in lecture, but they specified that n and m should be coprime positive integers, but in this case wouldn't n and m both be 2, and therefore not coprime?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For moduli, $2,3,4,5,6$

observe that

$n+1$ is divisible by lcm$(2,3,4,5,6)$

Answer (score 0):

Break everything up into moduli of prime powers. In your case, replace 
$n \equiv 5 \pmod 6$ with $n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ and  $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ (Because $6 = 2 \times 3$)

Then sort your congruences with respect to the prime bases.

\begin{eqnarray}
   n \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \\
   n \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \\
   n \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \\
   n \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \\
   n \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \\
   n \equiv 0 \pmod 7 \\
\end{eqnarray}

Note that $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ implies that $n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$. So we can remove $n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$. We end up with

\begin{eqnarray}
   n \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \\
   n \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \\
   n \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \\
   n \equiv 0 \pmod 7 \\
\end{eqnarray}

Now you can proceed using the CRT.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to notice is $n \equiv - 1 \mod k$.  So if $n \equiv -1 \mod \text{lcm}(2,3,4,5,6,7)$ then $n\equiv -1 \mod k$.

So $n\equiv -1 \mod \text{lcm}(2,3,4,5,6,7) = 420$, $n = 419 \mod 420$ is a perfectly acceptable solution.  By the chinese remainder theorem it is a unique solution.